# Processor noise

Tags: laptop, audio, cpu

I have a Acer Laptop (Aspire E 17 E5-773G-715H if that matters) with an Intel Core i7-6500U and an NVIDIA GeForce 940M running Win 10 and I'm annoyed by processor noise made by that notebook.

The noise appears when the laptop is in "idle" state and disappears when I drag a window around or hold down a key while in a textfield.

I already checked everything and can say for sure that the noise does **not** come from the HDD (Because there is an SSD in it) and neither from the fan. It seems to come from the speaker.

I've recorded audio of the noise in a quiet environment: https://vocaroo.com/i/s0xpEOnqtJ8L
(The noise isn't very loud, so you should turn up your volume. Yes, it's safe to listen to it in high volumes on Headphones, etc. No loud noises were made.)

I also already saw [this](https://superuser.com/questions/19968/processor-noise-what-generates-it) question, which an approved answere were given, saying that it could be the power supply, which here isn't the case.

EDIT: I also tried to disable the main sound device to see if it would make a difference, which it sadly didn't.

Any possible workaround (or maybe even solution) to make it stop is highly appreciated.

Suggestions are also welcome, as they may lead to the solution afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Noise can come from a wide variety of components in a computer.

You say it is not a power supply but even in a laptop you do have power switching and regulating circuits that all *can* create physical and electronic noise. You need *something* to convert the battery voltage into the various voltages used by the system.

Chances are that under "idle" load one of switching regulators is switching down to a lower frequency and one of its harmonics is creating noise in the speaker wires.

Alternatively it could be something known as "[coil whine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coil_noise)" where an inductor in the switching regulator is vibrating at an audible frequency. The fact you can hear it is for the same reasons as the noise from the speaker, but is created by a different mechanism.

There isn't really much that you, as a user, can do about this. It is either a design issue or a sign of age though it is not a problem in the long term.

You might be able to go into the [power plan options](https://superuser.com/questions/323738/what-is-minimum-and-maximum-processor-state-in-windows-7-power-management) and raise the minimum CPU power level to prevent the CPU from entering its lowest power state which might in turn stop the audible whine, but obviously this would waste at least some small amount more power and thus reduce battery life slightly.

Comment: "[...] or a sign of age" ... The notebook is rougly 4 months old. Sad.

Answer (score 1):

Processors don't make noise. Mechanical components like fans do. So likely when the CPU is idle, the fan gets set to a lower RPM speed, and it does make noise at this speed. It could also some other fan, but the connection to "idle" suggests it's the CPU fan.

Best solution: Open laptop, find the correct fan, and [lubricate fan](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/quiet-noisy-computer-fans-with-a-drop-of-oil/) at the point intended for lubrication.

If you can't open the laptop yourself, or you are afraid you will damage anything, pay someone else (computer shop etc.) to do it for it.

Comment: The notebook is new and I already checked for the fan. It is standing still. It's *not* the fan.

Comment: If you've already opened the notebook and checked *all* fans, you should also be able to identify the source of the noise while the notebook is open. If you didn't open the notebook and just checked if air is coming out: That's possibly only one fan of several.

Comment: I mention in the question that it's coming from the speakers... The fans are not the culprit.

Answer (score -2):

Since I can't comment ( new in this forum ):
1) don't oil things that don't know what will be the result of it ( spillage mostly, and more- it will get dusty and worse ).
2) If it happens on BAT power as well, it is nothing to do with charging and hrmonics
3) If some elec. component causing some noise- it may be a problem waiting to happen, and I advise to check it very seriously with your seller ( that it will get the right attention while your warranty is valid )

Best,
Guy

Comment: If you want to *efficiently* go from battery voltage (18V) down to the voltages use by the CPU (1.2V) then you *are* going to be using a switch mode power supply/converter. Just because it is battery powered doesn't mean that you can assume that everything works cleanly at the battery voltage. Harmonics **are** a problem in *any* high power battery powered equipment where components function at a different voltage to the battery supply.

Comment: Harmonics will occur from AC voltage and not DC

Comment: The you clearly have no idea what a switch mode power supply is. DC to DC conversion is either noisy, as in a switch mode power supply, or massively wasteful, as in linear power supplies. You **do** get noise from switch mode power supplies. I've spent years in electronics, I know this for a fact and you are quite plainly wrong.

Comment: I don't need any oil, because it's nothing mecanical that's failing... I already checked every moving part and it's *not* coming from them. It's coming from the speakers and related to the CPU/GPU usage.